# Extra blank space when printing multiple time

Tags: ios, swift, printing

I have an issue when I am trying to print the same page multiple times by pushing the print buttons that I created inside an iPad app project.
I have an extra blank space that appears at the top of the page (4cm).

If the printer url is nil I can print multiple times. I don't have any issue. But I don't want to have the printing pop up each time if a printer has been defined.
If a printer has been defined then I have a blank that appears starting from the second print page.

```
public var printerURL: URL?
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "PrinterURL") != nil
        { printerURL = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "PrinterURL")}
    }
    @IBAction func btnPrinterPressed(_ sender : UIButton) {
        self.printRightAway(url: "\(appUrl.url)\(vPK!)",success: { (bool) in
            if bool { self.hideSimpleHUD() }
        })
    }

func printRightAway (url : String, success:@escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        AF().DOWNLOAD(url, success: { (response,bool,message) in
            if bool == true {
                print(response)
                if UIPrintInteractionController.canPrint(response) {
                    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
                    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
                    printInfo.jobName = response.lastPathComponent
                    printInfo.outputType = .photo
                    printInfo.orientation = .portrait
                    
                printController.printInfo = printInfo
                printController.showsNumberOfCopies = true
                printController.showsPaperSelectionForLoadedPapers = true
                printController.printingItem = response
                let printerURL = UserDefaults.standard.url(forKey: "PrinterURL")
                if printerURL == nil {
                    printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
                } else {
                    let printer = UIPrinter(url: printerURL!)
                    printController.print(to: printer, completionHandler: {(controller, success, error) -> Void in
                        if success{
                            debugPrint("Printing Completed.")
                        }
                        else{
                            debugPrint("Printing Failed.")
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            success(true)
        } else {
            success (false)
            SharedClass.sharedInstance.alert(view: self, message: "An error occured \n\(message)".localized)
        }
    })
    { (Error, message) in
        SharedClass.sharedInstance.alert(view: self, message: "An error occured \n\(message)".localized)
        print ("KO: \(Error)")
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Observation: in `btnPrinterPressed`, this
 `if bool == true { self.hideSimpleHUD() } else { self.hideSimpleHUD() }` is completely meaningless.
Note, in `if` statements you can simply use `if bool {...}`

Comment: I might need to create a static shared singleton but I don't know how to write it correctly, someone could help me?